# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '...' not found

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to implement Django REST Framework and change my views accordingly. The FBV phase1 was changed to CBV DescriptorList

my template phase1.html

```
{% load rest_framework %}
...
<li><a href="{% url 'szenariohome' projectid %}">Return to Project Overview</a></li>
```

my urls.py in app named szenario

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/szenariohome/$', views.szenariohome, name='szenariohome'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/phase1/$', views.DescriptorList.as_view(), name='phase1'),
]
```

views.py

```
class DescriptorList (APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'szenario/phase1.html'

    def get(self, request, id):
        descriptor = Descriptor.objects.all()
        serializer = DescriptorSerializer(descriptor, many=True)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'descriptor': descriptor})

@permission_required_or_403('szenario.view_project', (Project, 'id','id'))
def szenariohome(request, id): als links, mitarbeiter, projectleader
    projectname = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=id)
    projectuser =  AbstractUser.objects.filter (workingproject=id)
    projectid = id
    context = {'projectname': projectname,  'projectuser': projectuser, 'projectid': projectid}
    return render(request, 'szenario/szenariohome.html', context)

@permission_required_or_403('szenario.view_project', (Project, 'id','id'))
def phase2(request, id):
    projectname = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=id)
    projectid = id
    context = {'projectname': projectname, 'projectid': projectid}
    return render(request, 'szenario/phase2.html', context)
```

I get the error "Reverse for 'szenariohome' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried".Without the line the template works. Template for phase2 has the same line and works fine. Could this problem occure because I used a serializer or a because i mixed CBV and FBV?

Any kind of help is appreciated,thanks.

Comment: May be you are forgetting `namespace` of your app, try (if you have a namespace) `{% url 'namespace:szenariohome' projectid %}`.

Comment: Added `{% url 'szenario:szenariohome' projectid %}` in template and `app_name = 'szenario'` in urls.py, didnt work.

Comment: You can't use `projectid` in the URL tag in the template, because you are not defining `projectid` anywhere in the view.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that django was unable to resolve an URL with the name `szenariohome` and the parameter `''` (empty string). It looks like `projectid` is not set and therefore the URL cannot be resolved.

Do you pass a proper `id` to your `DescriptorList`?

Also note that `id` is bad choice for a variable name in python as it clashes with the [builtin function id](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#id).

Comment: I added `projectid = id` in my view and `'projectid': projectid` to the response, which fixed the error, thanks!